# Trying to mine - nothing gets accepted

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration

I have a quite powerful server which pretty much sits idle and I thought I'd use its cycles for some pool mining with cpuminer. However, nothing seems to get accepted. I tried two pools (bitcoin.cz and bitminter.com) but it's all the same.

Here's the error I'm getting on bitminter:

```
[2013-12-07 08:56:04] < {"result":null,"error":[23,"Below difficulty",null],"id":4}
[2013-12-07 08:56:04] accepted: 0/209 (0.00%), 45.88 khash/s (booooo)
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Are you mining Bitcoin with cpuminer? Solo? You have a better chance of winning the lottery. Mine a CPU coin such as Quark or Primecoin, and trade for Bitcoin on an exchange such as BTC-e.com. ASICs (Application Specific Integrated Circuits) mine bitcoin magnitudes faster than a CPU since they are designed to computer SHA-256 and only SHA-256.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I had to add `-a sha256d` to the end of my command because cpuminer was defaulting to `scrypt` as the algorithm. Thus my command became:

`./minerd -a sha256d --url=stratum+tcp://mint.bitminter.com:3333 --userpass=user:pass`

But @mosca1337 is right, it was silly of me to assume that I can actually make any profit at this point from mining BTC with cpuminer. So I heeded his advice and looked at other currencies which can be mined with the CPU more efficiently.